# dauert oder dauern?

Tags: verb

I'm having trouble translating this English sentence: "The train ride can last between two and three hours"

> Die Bahnfahrt kann zwei bis drei Studen dauern

> Die Bahnfahrt kann zwei bis drei Studen dauert

The second version is marked as an incorrect sentence by Chatterbug. [The conjugation of dauern in Verbformen](https://www.verbformen.com/conjugation/dauern.htm) makes me think that both versions are correct. Is this right?

Comment: I think, this question should stay open. However the question might be very simple to answer for a native speaker, It is not asking for an entry in a conjugation table. The OP apparently does not know about the grammatical structure of modal verb sentences in German, or does not recognize the modal verb here. This is different than looking up the infinitive form of a verb in conjugation table.

Comment: The second sentence translates to "The train journey may takes two to three hours".

Comment: See for practice these three examples with the finite verb bolded: Die Bahnfahrt **dauert** zwei bis drei Stunden. Die Bahnfahrt **soll** zwei bis drei Stunden dauern. Die Bahnfahrt **muss** zwei bis drei Stunden dauern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The finite verb in the sentence is *kann*, i.e. the declined form of the modal verb *können*. [Modal verbs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalverb) (*können*, *wollen*, *mögen*, *dürfen*, *sollen*, *müssen*) are combined with the infinitive form of a verb. Hence, only the infinitive *dauern* is correct here.

Answer (score 2):

Dauern is the infinitive verb. Whenever a modal verb or a helping verb is used, you use the infinitive form for the second verb.

The train ride can last between two to three hours:

Die Bahnfahrt kann zwei bis drei Studen dauern

The train ride lasts between two to three hours:

Die Bahnfahrt dauert zwei bis drei Stunden. (In this case, since there is no modal verb, dauert is correct, conjugated wrt to "Bahnfahrt")